# problem with update ubuntu 14.04 dell vostro 3400

Tags: nvidia, updates, dell

my problems is the next:

I have installed ubuntu 14.04 in my laptop dell vostro 3400, before the installation ubuntu did not start due to the Nvidia video (black screen), so I was reading on internet a I edited the start changing "quiet splash" for "nomodeset", using that I can enter to ubuntu, when I am there I search for Nvidia driver and installed, then I restart the system and everything is ok, the system start normally, but when I accept the ubuntu updates and ask me to restart the system, it does not work again, it blocks when the ubuntu symbol appear at the begining, I edit again the system start changing to nomodeset but I does work.  I have reinstalled ubuntu twice but when I accept the updates that ubuntu suggest it does not work anymore.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Reinstall nvidia drivers after system upgrade. They use a patch that comes together with nvidia driver package and I suspect this to be the reason for your problems. So, upgrade, restart, and after restart press Ctrl+Alt+F1, input username and password and reinstall your nvidia drivers. Just don't forget to keep in mind the name for your nvidia drivers - eg: **nvidia-331** or similar. To manually install drivers you can run this command: **sudo apt-get install nvidia-xxx**, where xxx is the number for your driver package. Use **remove** instead of **install** to manually remove drivers first.

Comment: Hi Floppy, I did what you tell me, upgrade ubuntu, then restart the system, to remove and install nvidia drivers with commands but it did not work, the system do not go forward from the ubuntu sign.  I tried to enter using "nomodeset" but it did not work either.   What can I do now? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Once you get to the Ubuntu login sign, press together Ctrl+Alt+F1 which will get you to the console. Input your username and password, and run this command: **sudo nvidia-xconfig** . This will configure your system for your new nvidia drivers. Reboot and that's it. If it doesn't work after reboot, you need to run another command after you press again Ctrl+Alt+F1, and the new command is **sudo chmod -R ug+rwx /home/[username]**   Replace [username] with your username without brackets. This way you claim full permission for your user home folder. Hope either one asnwer will help.

Comment: Hola amigo,

Thanks for your help, I could fix the problem.  With your indications I could enter to ubuntu again and there I configured the video. Now all is working well.

Comment: Glad to hear it! I had to post an answer to your question so people know your problem is solved. If you want to mark my answer as the right one, you can do that, but if you think you need a more detailed answer you can wait until someone else will provide you with a better solution than my own. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall nvidia drivers after complete system upgrade. They use a patch that comes together with nvidia driver package and I suspect this to be the reason for your problems. So, upgrade, restart, and after restart press `Ctrl+Alt+F1`, input username and password and reinstall your nvidia drivers.

Just don't forget to keep in mind the name for your nvidia drivers - eg: **nvidia-331** or similar. To manually install drivers you can run this command:

```
     sudo apt-get install nvidia-xxx
```

where xxx is the number for your driver package. Use **remove** instead of **install** to manually remove drivers first.

Once you get to the Ubuntu login sign, press together `Ctrl+Alt+F1` which will get you to the console. Input your username and password, and run this command:

```
     sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

This will configure your system with your newly installed nvidia drivers. Reboot and that should do it.

If it still won't work after reboot, you need to run yet another command after you press again Ctrl+Alt+F1 key combination, and this new command is:

```
    sudo chmod -R ug+rwx /home/[username]
```

Replace [username] with your username without the brackets. This way you claim full permission for your user home folder. Hope either way will be of help.